# How to add array of elements in firebase?

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I want know how to simply store the data from the array to firebase. Let us consider that I having an array of element.

```
function Something() {
    var elements=new Array()
    elements[0]=10;
    elements[1]=20;
    elements[2]=30;

    database = firebase.database();
    var ref = database.ref('ExTable');
    ref.set(elements);
}
```

Will the **ref.set(elements);** function will save the data to my firebase DB?

Now this array contains three values, and how can I store them to firebase as nodes below any parent node. Like

```
+---Parent
      |
      |
      +---0
      |   |
      |   |
      |   +---10
      |
      |
      +---1
      |   |
      |   |
      |   +---20
      |
      |
      +---2
          |
          |
          +---10
```

I want to store them as like in the above example. Because my array sometimes contains various number of elements.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to store arrays in Firebase. They are a single object and cannot be edited, added to or queried and if a change needs to be made it must be deleted and re-written. See [Arrays Are Evil](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html). Perhaps if you can provide a use case we can recommend a solution. There's a bit of info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42041531/save-array-of-object-to-firebase-without-getting-0-1-2-as-key) and [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists)

Comment: @Jay, what if I need to temporarily store an array of data, which I plan to consume with a Cloud Function and then dispose of when the function resolves?

Comment: @katyusha It really depends on the use case. Perhaps you can post a question with your situation and details so we can better evaluate it. Arrays are very situational and there's usually better options but in some cases they can be ok.

Comment: @Jay, thanks! Just posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53795752/temporarily-store-array-of-data-in-firestore). There's really no code that I could provide that would add more context to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Just pass it with array of objects like shown below.

```
var array = [];

array.push({"name":"Barry"});
array.push({"name":"Allen"});

ref.push(array);
```