# Temporarily store array of data in Firestore

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

This question is in regards to a discussion that went on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141338/how-to-add-array-of-elements-in-firebase?noredirect=1#comment94440635_47141338).

I have a collection of urls in an array that I need to parse through using a Firebase Cloud Function. Instead of iterating through the URL's on the client (I could potentially have hundreds of items in this array) and making individual requests to the function, I'd rather store the entire array in Firestore, pass the ID of the collection to the function, grab the array on the server, iterate through it and perform some operations, and then either save it back to Firestore with a new ID and respond back to the client with that ID so it can consume/destroy, or just respond with an newly mutated array (not sure which one I'd like to use yet).

There doesn't seem to be a "preferred" way to store arrays with Firebase since it's generally considered evil, however, what if I don't plan to keep the data around for very long?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of just passing it as an array, assign it to an obj and pass that to Firestore.

```
const arr = ['url1', 'url2', 'url3'];
```

to

```
const obj = {
    arr: ['url1', 'url2', 'url3']
}
```

Comment: Note for next times that you can send list to firesore (if somehow this will make things more easy for you)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing array data as a list like this Java:

```
myDoc.put("urls", Arrays.asList("url1", "url2", "url2"));
```

that will result in

```
urls
   0: "url1"
   1: "url2"
   2: "url3"
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for leaving an answer! Any reasons you could share as to why this works better as opposed to just passing an object? I think I’m getting the same output as I would with your approach.

Comment: @katyusha I am not sure it works better.. I thought it would be good to include the actual code that writes the array data as a list. Your answer is fine and the result in Firebase may be the same. Probably should test it.